For a BQ SQL table, calculate the number of times the value in a given column switches in a given time period, partitioned by an ID value
Say I have a BQ table called employee_entries that is created and populated by the following SQL statements:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `my-project.my_dataset.employee_entries`  (
  employee_id STRING,
  entry_datetime DATETIME,
  entry_flag STRING,
  salary FLOAT64
);


INSERT INTO `my-project.my_dataset.employee_entries`  
(employee_id, entry_datetime, entry_flag, salary) VALUES
('1234', '2023-07-15 08:00:00', '1', 50000),
('1234', '2023-07-15 09:00:00', '2', 50000),
('1234', '2023-07-15 10:00:00', '0', 50000),
('1234', '2023-07-15 11:00:00', '0', 50000),
('1234', '2023-07-15 12:00:00', '1', 50000),
('1234', '2023-07-15 13:00:00', '3', 50000),
('5678', '2023-07-15 08:30:00', '2', 75000),
('5678', '2023-07-15 09:30:00', '2', 75000),
('5678', '2023-07-15 10:30:00', '3', 75000),
('5678', '2023-07-15 11:30:00', '4', 75000),
('5678', '2023-07-15 12:30:00', '4', 75000),
('5678', '2023-07-15 13:30:00', '0', 75000);

This will create the following example table:



employee_id
entry_datetime
entry_flag
salary




1234
2023-07-15 08:00:00
1
50000


1234
2023-07-15 09:00:00
2
50000


1234
2023-07-15 10:00:00
0
50000


1234
2023-07-15 11:00:00
0
50000


1234
2023-07-15 12:00:00
1
50000


1234
2023-07-15 13:00:00
3
50000


5678
2023-07-15 08:30:00
2
75000


5678
2023-07-15 09:30:00
2
75000


5678
2023-07-15 10:30:00
3
75000


5678
2023-07-15 11:30:00
4
75000


5678
2023-07-15 12:30:00
4
75000


5678
2023-07-15 13:30:00
6
75000



 
Problem:
I want to create a new table called employees_extended that has all the columns in this table but one additional column as well called entry_switches.
This entry_switches column is calculated from the other columns as such:
For each row in the original employee_entries table, for a particular employee_id, if all the rows for that employee are put in chronological order according to entry_datetime,
I want to count the number of times the value of the entry_flag switched before that the current row within the past 2 hours;
a "switch" meaning that the value is different for two chronologically consecutive entries for that employee_id.
For example if, chronologically, there are 4 entries in the past 2 hours for employee_id='1234' prior to the current row, and the 4 values of entry_flag were ['1',NULL,'0','0'] then this returns an entry_switches value of 2 for that row (the "switch" from 1 to NULL and then NULL to 0. Going from 0 to 0 is not included as a switch).
Expected Result Table:



employee_id
entry_datetime
entry_flag
salary
entry_switches




1234
2023-07-15 08:00:00
1
50000
0


1234
2023-07-15 09:00:00
2
50000
1


1234
2023-07-15 10:00:00
0
50000
2


1234
2023-07-15 11:00:00
0
50000
1


1234
2023-07-15 12:00:00
1
50000
1


1234
2023-07-15 13:00:00
3
50000
2


5678
2023-07-15 08:30:00
2
75000
0


5678
2023-07-15 09:30:00
2
75000
0


5678
2023-07-15 10:30:00
3
75000
1


5678
2023-07-15 11:30:00
4
75000
2


5678
2023-07-15 12:30:00
4
75000
1


5678
2023-07-15 13:30:00
6
75000
1



How can I achieve this resulting table using a SQL query in BQ?
Edit:
My Attempt:
WITH prev_entries AS ( -- get previous entry flags for each row
  SELECT *,
  LAG(entry_flag) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY entry_datetime) AS prev_entry_flag,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY entry_datetime) AS rn
  FROM `my-project.my_dataset.employee_entries`
),
-- deals with situation where there is no previous entry for an employee_id
entry_changes AS (
  SELECT * EXCEPT (prev_entry_flag, rn),
  CASE
    WHEN rn=1 THEN entry_flag
    ELSE prev_entry_flag
  END AS prev_entry_flag
  FROM prev_entries
)
SELECT employee_id,
entry_datetime,
entry_flag,
prev_entry_flag,
-- trying find a way to change this window fucntion to only count the last 2 hours, or find an alternative solution to this problem
SUM(CASE WHEN entry_flag IS DISTINCT FROM prev_entry_flag THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY entry_datetime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS switch_count
FROM entry_changes
ORDER BY 
employee_id, entry_datetime;


please share your attempted solution for this problem.

An example how to solve this using MySQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/9n-4U6s4  (I am not familiar with google-bigquery, but maybe you can rewrite this ?)

What is count entry_switches for sequence (3,4,0,4)?

@ValNik The count for that sequence would be 3. One for switching from 3 to 4, one for 4 to 0, and one for 0 to 4. This is assuming that those are the entry_flags for the same employee_id within the last 2 hours.

@Luuk I'm not actually counting the distinct flags, I'm counting the number of times it changes. So the same flag can repeat. e.g. if the flags for the last 2 hours for a particular employee_id are [1,2,1,2] then the entry_switches value for that row will be 3.

In example ['1',NULL,'0','0'] what is NULL?

@thegreenchipmunk: I must have mis-read/mis-understood that part of the question. Where is your attempted solution for this problem ?

@thegreenchipmunk: you can change it to count this way: https://dbfiddle.uk/shBpDI5C

@GeorginaSkibinski and Luuk, I have added in my attempted solution now.

@ValNik NULL is simply just a NULL value for entry_flag. This column can contain NULL values as well. NULL is treated like any other value. i.e. A change from any other value to NULL is counted as a "switch". NULL to NULL isn't a switch.

@Luuk My solution is something similar at the moment. The issue arises when I try to limit the switch-counting window to the past 2 hours only. Everything prior to the past 2 hours is ignored. I have added in my attempted solution which does something similar to what you have there.

If we can not use rows range by time in window function, we can (self) JOIN table with condition as
ROWS between <preceding 2 hours> and current

We use comparison as >= and <= to include first and current row.
Then, calculate entry_flag changes for every row for left table.
See example
with ranged_data as(
select ee1.*
  ,ee2.id id2,ee2.entry_datetime edt2, ee2.entry_flag flag2
  ,case when lag(ee2.entry_flag,1,ee2.entry_flag)
                over(partition by ee1.employee_id,ee1.entry_datetime 
                     order by ee2.entry_datetime)
         =ee2.entry_flag 
      then 0 
    when coalesce(
      lag(ee2.entry_flag,1,ee2.entry_flag)
                over(partition by ee1.employee_id,ee1.entry_datetime 
                     order by ee2.entry_datetime)
     ,ee2.entry_flag) is null
      then 0  
   else 1
  end chng_flag
from employee_entries ee1
left join employee_entries ee2 on ee1.employee_id=ee2.employee_id
  and ee2.entry_datetime<=ee1.entry_datetime
--  and ee2.entry_datetime>=dateadd(hour,-2,ee1.entry_datetime)
  and ee2.entry_datetime>=datetime_add(ee1.entry_datetime, interval -2 hour)
)
select id,employee_id,entry_datetime,entry_flag,salary
  ,sum(chng_flag) entry_switches
  ,string_agg(id2,'-') ids
  ,string_agg(case when flag2 is null then 'null' else flag2 end,'-') entry_flags
from ranged_data
group by employee_id,entry_datetime,entry_flag,salary

Used simplified check for null=null as coalesce(null, null) is null. May be, IS DISTINCT FROM is better here.
I will add id column to table only for clarity.
Demo for SQL Server

A version of this edited for BQ worked for me, thank you. I'll just add that for BQ (as with some other databases), the default value fed into the LAG function must be a constant, so NULLs can't be handled this way. But this solved my problem overall.
